# How do I get the total time it takes for a command to run?

Tags: bash, shell

I know you can get the compile time of each individual function using something like this:

```
xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme App clean build OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS="-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies" | grep .[0-9]ms | grep -v ^0.[0-9]ms | sort -nr > culprits.txt
```

or this

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode ShowBuildOperationDuration -bool YES
```

but how can I get the total build time printed out in command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly more efficient approach - here we call `date` only twice:

```
#!/bin/bash
start_time=$(date +%s)
# xcode command here
end_time=$(date +%s)
printf 'Elapsed time is %d seconds\n' $((end_time - start_time))
```

It's possible to get the current time even without forking, with `printf`:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf -v start_time '%(%s)T' -1
# xcode command here
printf -v end_time   '%(%s)T' -1
printf 'Elapsed time is %d seconds\n' $((end_time - start_time))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest way would be running something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

COMPILE_START=`date`
# your compile commands
COMPILE_END=`date`
printf "%s\n" $(( $(date -d "$COMPILE_END" "+%s") \
                - $(date -d "$COMPILE_START" "+%s") ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a bash command:

```
startTime=$(date +%s)

#Your commands

finishTime=$(date +%s)
timeElapsed=$((finishTime - startTime))
minute=$((timeElapsed / 60))
sec=$((timeElapsed % 60))
echo Total time: $minute min $sec sec
```